# Locking inside GetEnumerator()... what happens in a foreach with LINQ extensions?

Tags: c#, linq, locking, ienumerable

Given sample class:

```
internal Stuff<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : Foo
{
    private readonly object Sync = new object();
    private readonly T[] TObjects;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock(Sync)
            using (IEnumerator<T> safeEnum = TObjects.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator())
                while (safeEnum.MoveNext())
                    yield return safeEnum.Current;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    //other things
}
```

If I iterate this class in a foreach loop, the entire foreach loop is locked by the object's locking scheme.
My question is, what happens with this if I use this in a linq query, such as:

```
Stuff stuff = new Stuff() { /*some foos*/ };
var things = stuff.Where(/*some predicate*/);

foreach(Foo foo in things)
{
    //am i locked?
}

foreach(Foo foo in stuff.Where(/*some predicate*/))
{
    //am i locked?
}
```

So it boils down to, how does the query linking work under the hood?

Comment: *am I blocked?* Well not really. If you have a reference to this object, and no other code has it, then you will never be blocked. If you iterate it (on one thread say T1) and some other code has access to the exact same object and iterates it on another thread, it will be blocked until T1 is done iterating. The important part here is that the object gets locked and not the class.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Locked, not blocked. The locking mechanism propagates into the foreach loop, I'm asking if it also propagates into a foreach loop through a LINQ query made on the object.

Comment: LINQ is an abstraction on top of it so yes the same rules apply.

Comment: For the code that you have posted, you don't need a lock, since multiple threads get read only access to the data structure. In case you do some modification, then it's important to do thread safety, but I would rather use concurrent collection for that use case

Comment: Internally Linq Where is just reduced collection based on predicate, there's no difference between your two code snippets,  lock would have a role when more than one thread access the data structure, but not required for a read only enumerator

Comment: @MrinalKamboj This is obviously not the entire implementation of the class, this is only an example to demonstrate for the question. If you're saying the LINQ query still uses the base enumerator when executed, then my question is answered, ty.

Comment: Yes it would since you are using enumerator from an internal data structure, here an array. Until and unless you override and create a custom version of enumerator, here it comes from Enumerable class

Comment: Check the answer underneath, hope it helps in the further clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's review your code in detail, beside the small typo that `stuff<T>` shall be a class, your implementation of the `IEnumerator<T>` is as follows:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    lock (Sync)
     using (IEnumerator<T> safeEnum = TObjects.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator())
        while (safeEnum.MoveNext())
          yield return safeEnum.Current;
}
```

This is the implementation for `Enumeration`, not just `Enumerator`, since post getting an Enumerator, you are further processing the collection by moving the Enumerator further, ideally your custom implementation should have been like:

`IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => TObjects.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator()`, since the enumeration is done by the `foreach` loop, which does it by accessing the implemented enumerator and calling the `MoveNext` method and the `Current` property, thus current implementation could have been further concise

---

### Enumerator Implementation

`TObjects.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator()` implementation is as follows, it is accessing the `GetEnumerator()` implementation for the static class `System.Linq.Enumerable`, which internally has the implementation of the abstract class `Iterator<T>`.

1. `AsEnumerable()` is a simple extension method

   ```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> 
    source)
    {
       return source;
    }
   ```
2. Now since our source is an array `T[]`, an we are applying a `Where` clause, therefore as specified in following Enumerable implementation

   ```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
       if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
       if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
       if (source is Iterator<TSource>) return ((Iterator<TSource>)source).Where(predicate);
       if (source is TSource[]) return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>((TSource[])source, predicate);
       if (source is List<TSource>) return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
       return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
   }
   ```

We get `WhereArrayIterator`, whose implementation is as follows for the Enumeration / Iteration:

```
    class WhereArrayIterator<TSource> : Iterator<TSource>
    {
        TSource[] source;
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate;
        int index;

        public WhereArrayIterator(TSource[] source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
            this.source = source;
            this.predicate = predicate;
        }

        public override Iterator<TSource> Clone() {
            return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
        }

        public override bool MoveNext() {
            if (state == 1) {
                while (index < source.Length) {
                    TSource item = source[index];
                    index++;
                    if (predicate(item)) {
                        current = item;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                Dispose();
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> selector) {
            return new WhereSelectArrayIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, predicate, selector);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<TSource> Where(Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
            return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>(source, CombinePredicates(this.predicate, predicate));
        }
    }
```

As mentioned in the comments, Getting the Enumerator to the collection is thread safe, as its Read Only. All the code and class related details mentioned can be found on the [MS Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com), which has the API search browser

Comment: Again, there is a lot more going on in this class than I have showed you. I'm not asking if the collection is thread safe, or if anything is blocking anything else. I only want to know if the lock will propogate through the where extension into a foreach loop... If I followed the logic correctly in your post, you reinforce that it will, thank you.

Comment: Yes it would, since lock is all about thread and while it allows one thread, will block any other in same critical region and here all the code including linq Where will be on same thread, thus goes through.